# Cloud Test Environment For iOS Device

Tags: ios, testing, cloud, remote-access, seetest

I want to develop a testing tool/cloud through which user can remotely access iOS devices and can test.
Just like SeeTest Cloud [Refer this](https://cloud.experitest.com/index.html#/launchpad) 
Is there any Library with which I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Experitest has developed a device cloud which is a virtual device farm, with various devices and flavors.

There is an option for parallel execution as well, in the form Grid for both mobile and web.

However, these features can be used only with additional license. Here is the link to enroll for free trial:
https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/grid-execution-mobile/?am_force_theme_layout=desktop

Give it a try!